# Enabling styles in RTF field in Design tab

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We are using Tridion 2011 SP1.  Is there any way to enable styles in Design tabs of RTF field?  We have preview tab but editors are finding it as an extra activity to click on preview tab and see the look and feel.  In Tridion 5.3 in design tab as well style were applying. We have 2 paragraphs in RTF field but when we check it in design tab we can't see paragraph formattin rather `<p>` tag is treated as `</br>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Now Tridion has their own [stack exchange site](http://tridion.stackexchange.com).It have answer of this question [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/405/modify-the-wysiwyg-editor.)

Since you are also from Tridion community so I would like to request you to join it. See you there :-)

Thanks